# Adding textfields to jframe using graphics2d

Tags: java, swing, textfield, graphics2d

```
public class Contact {
   int x0,x1,y2=1500,x3=1500,a=0;
   JFrame jf;
   private JTextField name = new JTextField();
   private JTextField phone;
   private JButton start;
   boolean clicked=false;

   static Dimension dim=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   static int w=(int)dim.getWidth();    static int h=(int)dim.getHeight();
   IntroInner d=new IntroInner();   int c;

   public Contact() {

   }

   public void build() throws Exception{

      jf=new JFrame("THE COUNTRY CLUB");
      jf.getContentPane().add(d);
      jf.setSize(w,h);
      jf.setVisible(true);
      jf.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
      jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
   }

   public class IntroInner extends JPanel{

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g1){

        Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D) g1;

        FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics();
        int xpos=(int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth()/2-215;

        setFont(new Font("serif",Font.ITALIC,40));

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());

        Image im1=new ImageIcon("Images/bg.jpg").getImage();
        g.drawImage(im1,0,0,this);

        //g.rotate(a);
        Image im=new ImageIcon("Images/logo.png").getImage();
        g.drawImage(im,xpos,50,this);

        g.setColor(Color.white);

        g.drawString("Please Enter Your Details",400,400);

        g.drawString("Name:",400,475);

        g.drawString("Contact No:",400,550); 
     }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      new Contact().build();
  }
}
```

I reffered alot about implementing textfield to java frame using graphics2d in java. But didn't get any useful opinion. I have found something here in stackoverflow also. But that too didn't helped me. Can anybody help me in this. The expected output of this program isgiven below: Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this when there are already full functional components available which do the job for you?

Comment: `I reffered alot about implementing textfield to java frame using graphics2d in java` - I have absolutely no idea what that statement means. Graphics are used to paint something on the GUI. A text field is used to accept keyboard input. How are the two concepts related?

Answer (score 3):

OK, so you probably need to take a step back and see the two aspects here:

- One aspect is that you can directly draw on a Graphics2D object, printing strings, draw lines, fill rectangles, etc... While this can be very interesting in some situations (if you want to perform very custom drawings, for example), this is a very low level approach. You're in charge of doing a lot of things. If you would consider handling a text field, this would mean that you would have to draw a background, a border, a string as it get typed, make a blinking caret, etc... This can easily become very cumbersome and tedious to maintain
- The other aspect is that Swing provides a bunch of component which does already all the tedious work I just talked about. While it cannot handle all cases, simple cases such as labels, textfield, images, etc... already have a built-in implementation which basically avoids you the cumbersome work to do it yourself. The only thing left for you is to explain how and where you want your components to appear. This is where LayoutManager's come into play.

Here is a small example (amongst many other) which shows you the gist of doing such thing:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class BasicSwingTest {

    protected void initUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel image  = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Duke3D.png/220px-Duke3D.png")));
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(image, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        panel.add(new JLabel("Name: "));
        JTextField name = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(name);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Contact no: "));
        JTextField contactNumber = new JTextField(15);
        panel.add(contactNumber);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Enter your details"));
        mainPanel.add(panel);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new BasicSwingTest().initUI();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

And the outcome:

[image]

Here is a second example (looking a bit more like your image, although it needs a few tweaks):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BasicSwingTest2 {

    private static final Font FONT = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18);

    protected void initUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel contentPane = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.pd4pic.com/images/blue-background-simple.jpg")));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        JTextField name = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField contactNumber = new JTextField(15);

        panel.add(getLabel("Name: "), gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        panel.add(name, gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        panel.add(getLabel("Contact no: "), gbc);
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        panel.add(contactNumber, gbc);

        JLabel topLabel = getLabel("Please enter you details");
        topLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(topLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JLabel getLabel(String text) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setFont(FONT);
        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        return label;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new BasicSwingTest2().initUI();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the immediate help.But can you please check my question again. It's a part of graphics2d.

Comment: @thampijoseph sorry but I don't get why you want so hard to work with graphics2d. You should probanly re-read my answer in depth an try to understand what it says. You don't need to use Graphics2D to achieve the picture you showed. It can easily be achieve with Swing components.

Comment: This is the requirement that I got from my client side and they are not ready to compromise :(

Comment: @thampijoseph Using Swing components means that, eventually, you are using Graphics2D. The only thing is that you let the Swing components do the work with Graphics2D. You have a much higher and much simpler level by using Swing components. If you want to do that yourself, all you will do is try to do the same as Swing components do, and most likely doing it a lot less good than Swing does. Using Swing is in no way making a compromise, it's only making your life easier and still using Graphics2D.

Comment: @thampijoseph See also my edit and the new example I appended at the end. It looks more or less like your sample image. Needs a few tweaks, but the basic idea is there.